# How to cast PSObject to SecureString. Cannot implicitly convert

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

Let's say I am using the following in PowerShell to create an encrypted file:

```
$PWD = Read-host "Enter Password" -assecurestring
$PWD | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (1..16)| out-file encrypted.txt
```

In C# I am using a PowerShell runspace to read the encrypted file and convert to a SecureString:

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{              
    powershell.AddScript("get-content c:\\tools\\scripts\\encrypted.txt | convertTo-SecureString -key (1..16)");
    foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
    { 
         Console.WriteLine(PSObject); //This returns System.Security.SecureString
         Console.WriteLine(result.GetType()); //This returns System.Security.SecureString
         ManagementGroupConnectionSettings mgSettings = new 
         ManagementGroupConnectionSettings(serverName);
         mgSettings.UserName = name;
         mgSettings.Domain = userDomain;
         //I am trying to pass this to a field that accepts SecureString
         //However there is an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to 'System.Security.SecureString' 
         mgSettings.Password = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but try using the base object and then casting:

```
mgSettings.Password = result.BaseObject as SecureString;
```

Comment: @JVilla right, forgot this is wrapped in a PSObject, see my edit.

Comment: mgSettings.Password = result.BaseObject as SecureString; That did the trick @briantist  Thanks!